# How do I convert t2.small to t2.large?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a snapshot, but I see no option to create a new instance from it during the launch wizard.

It says in the EC2 price list that the instance storage for this range is "EBS Only", if that makes any difference.

Comment: There's no such thing as a `t1.small`.  Did you mean `t2.small`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to specifically have a snapshot and then upgrading machine type. Just follow these steps to convert any machine type to other.

- Open AWS EC2 console
- select your desired instance
- Stop the instance
- After the instance has stopped
- Goto Actions > Instance Settings > Change Instance type
- Select your desired instance type.
- Again start your instance.

**Method 2**

If you want to launch a new instance from that snapshot, then follow these steps.

- Select the snapshot
- Goto Actions > Create image
- Define parameters there.
- And then launch a new instance from that AMI

All done.

:)